# when I use protoc gave me the following error "--ts_proto_out: protoc-gen-ts_proto: %1 is not a valid Win32 application". Anyone knows why?

Tags: nestjs, grpc, protoc

I'm using protoc and is not working properly. (--ts_proto_out: protoc-gen-ts_proto: %1 is not a valid Win32 application) Anyone can help me?
I am using

- windows 11 pro
- nest js 10.1.18
- Language: typescript

The command is:
protoc --plugin=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts_proto --ts_proto_out=./ --ts_proto_opt=nestJs=true ./src/proto/com.proto

I'am compiling a microservice application using nest Js

Answer (score 0):

use this command:

```
protoc --plugin=protoc-gen-ts_proto="C:\path\to\your\project\folder\node_modules\.bin\protoc-gen- 
ts_proto.cmd" --ts_proto_out=./ --ts_proto_opt=nestJs=true ./proto/yourfile.proto
```